# Generate DDLs from Hive tables and write each DDLs to a different .txt file

Tags: php, python, sql, linux, hive

I am trying to learn how to create DDLs for all tables in a given database of Hive automatically.

For example, I have a database named abc_db. I have written a Hive script to write all the tables into a file called abc_db.txt.The output in the file are all the tables inside abc_db line by line.

```
 `hive -e 'show tables in abc_db' > abc_db.tx`t
```

I want to be able to loop through all of its table and write the DDLs for each table to my directory with their respective table names.

Here is my start:

```
hive -e "show tables in abc_db" > d.txt

cat d.txt | while read LINE;
do
  echo "## Table Name:" $LINE
  mkdir $LINE
  cd $LINE
  eval "hive -e 'show create table in $LINE' | grep -v ^$ | grep -v Logging | grep -v tab_name | tee $LINE.tables.txt"
done
```

Given the above information any ideas or starting points on how automatically generate all DDLs from the table and write each DDL to a separate file?

Answer (score 1):

Adapt as needed.  Takes the source schema (processing all tables in the schema) and the output directory as arguments.

Script: `gen-ddl`

```
#!/bin/bash
SCHEMA="$1"
OUTDIR="$2"
if [[ $# -ne 2 ]]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 <schema-name> <out-dir>"
  exit 1
fi
mkdir -p "$OUTDIR"
TABLES=$(hive -e "show tables in $SCHEMA;")
for TABLE in $TABLES; do
  DDL_FILE="$OUTDIR/$TABLE-create-ddl.sql"
  echo -e "Generating DDL ...\n... table: $TABLE\n... file:  $DDL_FILE"
  hive -e "show create table $SCHEMA.$TABLE" > "$DDL_FILE"
done
echo "Done."
```

Usage:

```
$ ./gen-ddl <schema-name> <out-dir>
```

Comment: I have one question: where to I name the output file? After "DDL_File"?

Comment: could I chat you?

Comment: See line `DDL_FILE="$OUTDIR/$TABLE-create-ddl.sql'.  The filename is the table name appended with '-create-ddl.sql'.  You can modify to meet your needs.